# Google Signin on React Native(+Firebase) for both platforms (IOS, Android)

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am building an app using React Native with firebase using React Native. So far I am using one code of React Native for both IOS and Android. Now I want to implement Google Signin, later I want to include Facebook and Github logins, but I cannot find how to implement it for both platforms. As far as I understand it, IOS needs some podfile, and Android requires google-services.json. I found some tutorials on how to connect Google signin on each platform. If I follow both tutorials(including installing potfile and service,json), would it work on both platforms? Is it possible to have 1 code that works on both platforms?

Answer (score 0):

these can be used for google and facebook logins
https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin
https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/

Comment: First, thank you. Yes, but if you look at the "Project setup and initialization" section, it has separate guide for IOS and Android. If I follow both guides, would my code run on both platforms or do I need two versions of code?